# How to read the config parameter inside a interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor

Does exist a way to consult the value of object config inside a interceptor? I want to view the config values before and after every request.

In the following code, how can I print the entire structure of config and response object in their respective case?

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    }

    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply print the config and response object using :

```
console.log("config : "+ angular.toJson(config));
console.log("response : "+ angular.toJson(response));
```